Drawing cycles around and across cuts
I want to draw cycles (or paths) around and across the cuts on the complex plane for the following function (where I have put the cuts between [z1,z2] and [z3,z4]). Also want to compute the discontinuities/jumps across those cuts.
z1 = 1 ;
z2 = 5 - 2 I;
z3 = 10 + 3 I ;
z4 = 14;

f = 1/((z1 - z2)*Sqrt[-((z - z1)/(z1 - z2))]
  Sqrt[-((z - z2)/(z1 - z2))])
 1/((z3 - z4)*Sqrt[-((z - z3)/(z3 - z4))]
  Sqrt[-((z - z4)/(z3 - z4))]);

 fRe = f /. z -> x + I y // Re;
 fIm = f /. z -> x + I y // Im;

 pRe = Plot3D[fRe, {x, z1 - 6, z4 + 6}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {-.3, .3}, PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 300];
 pIm = Plot3D[fIm, {x, z1 - 6, z4 + 6}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {-.3, .3}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ImageSize -> 300]; 
 {pRe, pIm}

